# Find the excess rows between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
    'b': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
    'b': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
})
```

I want to compare both these data frames and find all the extra rows in df1 that are not in df2.

The desired output should be like this:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

I have tried merge but this creates extra results since there are duplicates
and I don't want to remove them.

Is there a good way of approaching this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first step, you can find the difference between row counts in each table:

```
diff = df1.value_counts().sub(df2.value_counts(), fill_value=0)
```

Result:

```
a  b
0  0   -1.0
   1    1.0
1  1    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Based on the previous result you can build a new dataframe with a difference:

```
lst = []
for (a, b), num in diff[diff > 0].iteritems():
    lst.extend([{'a': a, 'b': b}] * int(num))
    
pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  0  1
1  1  1
2  1  1
```

Comment: Hi Mkyola, thanks for the help. I just noticed that the output should also include (0,1) since that is not included in df2. Is there an adjustment to your code that would cater for this?